# What is the answer to Paul’s rhetorical question in 1 Corinthians 10:29-30?

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul

1 Corinthians 10:29-30 NASB

> “I mean not your own conscience, but the other man’s; for why is my freedom judged by another’s conscience? If I partake with thankfulness, why am I slandered concerning that for which I give thanks?”

‭‭
What is Paul’s own answer to the questions that he poses here? Verses 31 through 33 talk about eating and drinking to the glory of God and not giving offense to either Jews or Greeks, but I’m still not exactly sure how that answers the question of why his freedom is judged by another man’s conscience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is found in 1 Corinthians 10:31:

> 31 Whether therefore ye eat, or drink, or whatsoever ye do, do all to
> the glory of God.

> If I partake with thankfulness, why am I slandered concerning that for which I give thanks?

A sincere thankfulness will result in focusing more on God's glory. Focusing more on God's glory will lead one to act in a fashion to not be slandered - Paul stresses this at many points in his theology.

> for why is my freedom judged by another’s conscience?

Because - for the glory of God - you are supposed to love your neighbour as yourself, and to love God with soul, heart, strength and mind. This leaves no room for a possessiveness of one's own freedom.

Both questions are wrong questions, as both are focused on the consumer rather than the God whose glory ought to be foremost. A truth that Paul reveals in the very next verse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Similar to what I was thinking, but phrased a little differently. I like the phrasing of those two questions being the wrong questions and the point being the glory of God. Well said!

Answer (score 0):

1 Corinthians 2:14-15 (NASB)

> But a natural man does not accept the things of the Spirit of God, for they are foolishness to him; and he cannot understand them, because they are spiritually appraised. But he who is spiritual appraises all things, yet he himself is appraised by no one.

1 Corinthians 4:3-4 (NASB)

> But to me it is a very small thing that I may be examined by you, or by any human court; in fact, I do not even examine myself. For I am conscious of nothing against myself, yet I am not by this acquitted; but the one who examines me is the Lord.

Paul’s freedom is found in God, not in the traditions imposed on him by the culture and traditions of his former life.

John 8:31-32 (NASB

> So Jesus was saying to those Jews who had believed Him, “If you continue in My word, then you are truly disciples of Mine; and you will know the truth, and the truth will make you free.

‘In’ is the keyword of where Paul resides. ‘In’ Christ.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1 Corinthians 10:29-30 NASB

### “I mean not your own conscience, but the other man’s; for why is my freedom judged by another’s conscience? If I partake with thankfulness, why am I slandered concerning that for which I give thanks?”

To put it simply and keeping the religious mumbo jumbo to a minimum. Here is was this is saying in plain english.

"***for why is my freedom judged by another’s conscience?"***

is the main part of this verse.

As human, we all based what's right or wrong according to us, the individual.  Sam might do something Joe doesn't like. So its human nature for Joe to "judge" sam.

This can because of different cultures, different understandings and so on.

It's a rhetorical question, asking why do people judge others who live differently than them.

That's what the verse means in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

1 Cor 10:23-33 is such an abused passage, used to justify all kinds of things.  For example, it has been used to suggest that we can eat anything so long as we give thinks to God for it.  This might include a diet of nothing but cream cakes and custard, or, some of the modern crank-diets that have been shown to be quite damaging to to human health. See appendix below.

That is, 1 Cor 10:23-33 does not give license to abuse our bodies with bad practices such drunkenness, illicit drugs, laziness and poor diet.

So, what is this passage saying and what is it not saying?

The main matter here is the offering of food to idols.  Paul explicitly says this in V27-29 -

> If an unbeliever invites you to a meal and you want to go, eat
> anything set before you without raising questions of conscience. **But
> if someone tells you, “This food was offered to idols,”** then do not
> eat it, for the sake of the one who told you and for the sake of
> conscience the other one’s conscience, I mean, not your own. For why
> should my freedom be determined by someone else’s conscience?

Thus, the problem Paul is discussing here is not what the food is, but whether it was offered to idols as part of a pagan idol ceremony (as was common).  Indeed, such practices do not materially alter the food and should not bother a person whose faith in the true God is strong.  Paul makes this point in V25, 26.

However, so as not to be a stumbling block for others (V32), Paul advised either not to ask, or, if one does become aware of the idol offering then refuse the food for the sake of those whose consciences are weaker.

Thus, Paul did not worry, personally, about food offered to idols because such gods do not actually exist but did not want to cause others to lose their faith.

**APPENDIX - NT on the subject of Personal Health**

The New Testament contains a number of instructions to remain healthy.  [The Torah has numerous health laws such as personal hygiene laws, quarantine laws, and dietary laws.]  It is in modern times that the value of many of these has become clear.

The New Testament contains several health instructions that directly reflect the OT.

- Rom 12:1 – our bodies are to be a living sacrifice to God.
- 1 Cor 6:19, 20 – glorify (increase the honor and reputation of) God in your bodies.
- 3 John 2 – good physical health is as important as spiritual health.
- Phil 3:19 – those who make a god of their stomach will be destroyed.
- Gal 6:7, 8, “Do not be deceived: God cannot be mocked. A man reaps what he sows.  Whoever sows to please their flesh, from the flesh will reap destruction”.
- Acts 15:20, 29, 21:25 – do not eat blood.
- Worry and anxiety cure, 1 Peter 5:7

This means that Christians should acquaint themselves with good health practices by remaining informed about a good lifestyle (including diet, hygiene, exercise, etc) so that we may glorify God in all things.

Comment: I think the main issue is why does it cause conscience issue in other. What does it mean about the conscience bothered.

Comment: @Michael16 - I answered that in the final paragraph - some are overly sensitive souls place great emphasis on whether some food is offered to idols or not - Paul was no so concerned but did not want to be a stumbling block to weaker (less mature)  Christians

Answer (score 0):

The subject "me" or self is hypothetical representing indefinite subject. It should be read the same as the "you" in the paragraph. Why should your, or someone's freedom is questioned by someone else's conscience. Let him eat who wants. But you may avoid eating for the sake of weaker conscience of others. The hypothetical self is same as in Romans 7. It's not referring to Paul himself. He is not relevant to the hypothetical situation of the idol food offering.